# Chart.js column graph not rendering data

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to create a crypto homepage which tracks and manages data relating to bitcoin.
Currently I am rendering a graph which displays the amount of miners in a pool using the blockchain.com API, and the graph shows up with no columns inside it, just a blank border and axes.

I tried to render the graph using this code:

```
tradeVolumeBTC()

var columns = []

const chartAPI = 'https://api.blockchain.info/pools?timespan=5days'

document.onload = function getData() {
  fetch(chartAPI)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(toFindData => columns.push(toFindData['AntPool'], toFindData['BTC M4'], toFindData['Foundry USA'], toFindData['ViaBTC'], toFindData['Unknown'], toFindData['BTC.com'], 
      toFindData['F2Pool'], toFindData['Binance Pool'], toFindData['Mara Pool'], toFindData['Poolin'], toFindData['SBI Crypto'], toFindData['Ultimus'], toFindData['Braiins Poo'],))
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['AntPool', 'BTC M4', 'Foundry USA', 'ViaBTC', 'Unknown', 'BTC.com', 'F2Pool', 'Binance Pool', 'Mara Pool', 'Poolin', 'SBI Crypto', 'Ultimus', 'Braiins Pool'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'BTC Pools',
        data: columns,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

The data returned from the blockchain API is:

```
{"ViaBTC":79,"Binance Pool":57,"Foundry USA":213,"F2Pool":85,"AntPool":194,"Mara Pool":32,"Poolin":12,"Unknown":29,"BTC M4":8,"SBI Crypto":13,"Ultimus":4,"BTC.com":4,"Braiins Pool":6}
```

and instead of the graph rendering correctly with columns showing up, instead none render, as shown:

[image: BTC website with no rendered columns:]

Comment: Your chart is loading before data is fetched in the dom. You need to render the chart after the async fetch function returns the data

Answer (score 0):

`columns` is empty when you render the Chart. Render the chart when you receive the data from the API. I moved the render method in the callback function.

```
tradeVolumeBTC();

var columns = [];

const chartAPI = "https://api.blockchain.info/pools?timespan=5days";

document.onload = function getData() {
  fetch(chartAPI)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((toFindData) =>
      columns.push(
        toFindData["AntPool"],
        toFindData["BTC M4"],
        toFindData["Foundry USA"],
        toFindData["ViaBTC"],
        toFindData["Unknown"],
        toFindData["BTC.com"],
        toFindData["F2Pool"],
        toFindData["Binance Pool"],
        toFindData["Mara Pool"],
        toFindData["Poolin"],
        toFindData["SBI Crypto"],
        toFindData["Ultimus"],
        toFindData["Braiins Poo"]
      );
      const ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          labels: [
            "AntPool",
            "BTC M4",
            "Foundry USA",
            "ViaBTC",
            "Unknown",
            "BTC.com",
            "F2Pool",
            "Binance Pool",
            "Mara Pool",
            "Poolin",
            "SBI Crypto",
            "Ultimus",
            "Braiins Pool",
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "BTC Pools",
              data: columns,
              borderWidth: 1,
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        },
      });      
    );
};
```

Learn more about [Asychronous programming](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_asynchronous.asp)

Comment: When using this method, the canvas display is blank and there is no visible graph.