# Chart.js column graph still not rendering data

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to create a crypto homepage which tracks and manages data relating to bitcoin.
Currently I am rendering a graph which displays the amount of miners in a pool using the blockchain.com API, and the graph shows up with no columns inside it, just a blank border and axes.

I tried to render the graph using this code:

```
var columns = []

const chartAPI = 'https://api.blockchain.info/pools?timespan=5days'

document.onload = function getData() {
  fetch(chartAPI)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(toFindData => columns.push(
      toFindData["AntPool"],
      toFindData["BTC M4"],
      toFindData["Foundry USA"],
      toFindData["ViaBTC"],
      toFindData["Unknown"],
      toFindData["BTC.com"],
      toFindData["F2Pool"],
      toFindData["Binance Pool"],
      toFindData["Mara Pool"],
      toFindData["Poolin"],
      toFindData["SBI Crypto"],
      toFindData["Ultimus"],
      toFindData["Braiins Poo"]
    ));

  const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['AntPool', 'BTC M4', 'Foundry USA', 'ViaBTC', 'Unknown', 'BTC.com', 'F2Pool', 'Binance Pool', 'Mara Pool', 'Poolin', 'SBI Crypto', 'Ultimus', 'Braiins Pool'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'BTC Pools',
          data: columns,
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    });
}
```

The data returned from the blockchain API is:

```
{"ViaBTC":79,"Binance Pool":57,"Foundry USA":213,"F2Pool":85,"AntPool":194,"Mara Pool":32,"Poolin":12,"Unknown":29,"BTC M4":8,"SBI Crypto":13,"Ultimus":4,"BTC.com":4,"Braiins Pool":6}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class=" max-w-sm w-full lg:max-w-full lg:flex flex-row">
                <div class="h-48 lg:h-auto lg:w-48 flex-none bg-cover rounded-t lg:rounded-t-none lg:rounded-l text-center overflow-hidden">
                </div>
                <div class="border-2 border-gray-400 lg:border-gray-400 bg-white rounded p-4 flex flex-row justify-between leading-normal">
                  <canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>          
          </div>    
        </div>
      <script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

and instead of the graph rendering correctly, it does not display at all as shown:
[Canvas is blank:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMtvm.png)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? And what does the columns array look like?

Comment: When logging the array to the console after the function is called it displays: [] with a length of 0
Furthermore, the HTML is displayed below by the following:

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HTML in there instead of in a comment.

Comment: Where do you console.log? Between the fetch and `const ctx`?

Comment: I did console.log(columns) after the whole function was called. Outside of it which displays: 
Array(0)
length: 0

When i console.log between the fetch and const ctx, it displays:
[]
And when i console.log anywhere inside of the function nothing is displayed on the console.

Comment: I was overlooking, that fetch is an asynchronous function. So, you either have to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) it or put the creation of the chart into the second `then` after pushing the values to the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-can-i-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question as you created previously: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77611814/8017690

Comment: Where would I put the await for the fetch? I also tried putting the chart creation into the second .then after pushing the values into the array however nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you used the `window.onload`.

In this way:

```
window.onload = function() {
  getData();
};
```

See it in action here:

```js
let columns = [];

const chartAPI = 'https://api.blockchain.info/pools?timespan=5days';

function getData() {

  fetch(chartAPI)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(toFindData => {
      columns.push(
        toFindData["AntPool"],
        toFindData["BTC M4"],
        toFindData["Foundry USA"],
        toFindData["ViaBTC"],
        toFindData["Unknown"],
        toFindData["BTC.com"],
        toFindData["F2Pool"],
        toFindData["Binance Pool"],
        toFindData["Mara Pool"],
        toFindData["Poolin"],
        toFindData["SBI Crypto"],
        toFindData["Ultimus"],
        toFindData["Braiins Poo"]
      );

      const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['AntPool', 'BTC M4', 'Foundry USA', 'ViaBTC', 'Unknown', 'BTC.com', 'F2Pool', 'Binance Pool', 'Mara Pool', 'Poolin', 'SBI Crypto', 'Ultimus', 'Braiins Pool'],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'BTC Pools',
            data: columns,
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
  getData();
};
```

```html
<div class=" max-w-sm w-full lg:max-w-full lg:flex flex-row">
  <div class="h-48 lg:h-auto lg:w-48 flex-none bg-cover rounded-t lg:rounded-t-none lg:rounded-l text-center overflow-hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="border-2 border-gray-400 lg:border-gray-400 bg-white rounded p-4 flex flex-row justify-between leading-normal">
    <canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

There is another approach by using: [**`DOMContentLoaded`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```js
let columns = [];

const chartAPI = 'https://api.blockchain.info/pools?timespan=5days';

function getData() {

  fetch(chartAPI)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(toFindData => {
      columns.push(
        toFindData["AntPool"],
        toFindData["BTC M4"],
        toFindData["Foundry USA"],
        toFindData["ViaBTC"],
        toFindData["Unknown"],
        toFindData["BTC.com"],
        toFindData["F2Pool"],
        toFindData["Binance Pool"],
        toFindData["Mara Pool"],
        toFindData["Poolin"],
        toFindData["SBI Crypto"],
        toFindData["Ultimus"],
        toFindData["Braiins Poo"]
      );

      const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['AntPool', 'BTC M4', 'Foundry USA', 'ViaBTC', 'Unknown', 'BTC.com', 'F2Pool', 'Binance Pool', 'Mara Pool', 'Poolin', 'SBI Crypto', 'Ultimus', 'Braiins Pool'],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'BTC Pools',
            data: columns,
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  getData();
});
```

```html
<div class=" max-w-sm w-full lg:max-w-full lg:flex flex-row">
  <div class="h-48 lg:h-auto lg:w-48 flex-none bg-cover rounded-t lg:rounded-t-none lg:rounded-l text-center overflow-hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="border-2 border-gray-400 lg:border-gray-400 bg-white rounded p-4 flex flex-row justify-between leading-normal">
    <canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

And with: [**`document.onreadystatechange`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event), that must be handled with the [**`document.readyState`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) property, like this:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    getData();
  }
};
```

Here is the complete example:

```js
let columns = [];

const chartAPI = 'https://api.blockchain.info/pools?timespan=5days';

function getData() {

  fetch(chartAPI)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(toFindData => {
      columns.push(
        toFindData["AntPool"],
        toFindData["BTC M4"],
        toFindData["Foundry USA"],
        toFindData["ViaBTC"],
        toFindData["Unknown"],
        toFindData["BTC.com"],
        toFindData["F2Pool"],
        toFindData["Binance Pool"],
        toFindData["Mara Pool"],
        toFindData["Poolin"],
        toFindData["SBI Crypto"],
        toFindData["Ultimus"],
        toFindData["Braiins Poo"]
      );

      const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['AntPool', 'BTC M4', 'Foundry USA', 'ViaBTC', 'Unknown', 'BTC.com', 'F2Pool', 'Binance Pool', 'Mara Pool', 'Poolin', 'SBI Crypto', 'Ultimus', 'Braiins Pool'],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'BTC Pools',
            data: columns,
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
}

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    getData();
  }
};
```

```html
<div class=" max-w-sm w-full lg:max-w-full lg:flex flex-row">
  <div class="h-48 lg:h-auto lg:w-48 flex-none bg-cover rounded-t lg:rounded-t-none lg:rounded-l text-center overflow-hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="border-2 border-gray-400 lg:border-gray-400 bg-white rounded p-4 flex flex-row justify-between leading-normal">
    <canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the great help. What was the difference between using window.onload may i ask?

Comment: Sure! In Vanilla JavaScript `window.onload` is triggered when it loads the entire page with its CSS and JavaScript files at once, however, `document.onload` doesn't exist actually. There is already a question about that in this link: [JS window.onload Usage Vs Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092746/js-window-onload-usage-vs-document). On the other hand, there is a [`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) { });`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) which is triggered before `window.onload`.

Comment: And also, there is the [`document.onreadystatechange = function () { };`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event) is a Document event where it can be used with the `document.readyState` is `"complete"` to run other methods.

Comment: @C0SM1C0ST I've updated my answers with a couple of examples to help you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the working examples, I really appreciate the explanation and feedback, Thankyou!